# I found that the result of `UCallExpression.resolve()` is `null` when I execute lint detect

Tags: android, lint

When I execute lint detect,I found that the result of `UCallExpression.resolve()` is `null` in `UElementVisitor#DelegatingPsiVisitor.visitMethodCallExpression`.

This problem only occurs when detecting some methods, and different methods in the same class will not have this problem.

Pray for answers ...

Comment: I also found the problem. class org.jetbrains.uast.java.JavaUCallExpression resolve is null